# My Concrete5 Page Types Will Only Use Default.php

Tags: php, themes, concrete5

For some reason, my theme will not use any of the .php templates that I have built. For instance, in my theme file, there is a template called "gridLayout.php" In Page Types I have created a "Grid Layout" page type with handle "gridLayout"—shouldn't that be all I need to do? I cannot see the template in the Defaults mode, or when I create a specific page of that type. I also tried de-activating and re-activating the theme, thinking that would refresh things; still nothing. I must be missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

page types ought to follow concrete5 naming rules, grid_layout.php is preferred to gridLayout.php also concrete5 will only ask you to register a new page type upon theme installation or using the inspect button.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options here. One, de-activating the theme is not enough. Uninstalling and installing the theme will restart the process of identifying page types. Even easer though is the "Inspect" button for the custom theme. It will identify page templates that are not being used and ask you to create said page type.

Answer (score 0):

Check your cache settings in Concrete5.  Make sure you turn off all caching while developing.